# Go import from package's vendor

Tags: go, go-modules, govendor

How can I specify to import/use a package from the vendor instead from the GOPATH/GOROOT?

```
$GOPATH/src/
$GOPATH/src/github.com/
$GOPATH/src/github.com/myproject/mypkg
$GOPATH/src/github.com/myproject/mypkg/mypkgfile1.go
```

```
package mypkg
import "github.com/someproject/somepkg" // importing from vendor

type MyStruct struct {
  Config somepkg.SomeStruct1
}
func New(config somepkg.SomeStruct1) MyStruct {...} 
func (m *MyStruct) DoSomething() {
  a := somepkg.SomeStruct1{}
  b := somepkg.SomeStruct2{}
  // do something with 'a' and 'b'
  out := somepkg.SomeFunc(a) 
}
func (m *MyStruct) MyFunc(input SomeStruct1) (output SomeStruct2, err error) {...}
```

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/myproject/mypkg/mypkgfile2.go
$GOPATH/src/github.com/myproject/mypkg/vendor/github.com/someproject/somepkg/
$GOPATH/src/github.com/myproject/mypkg/vendor/github.com/someproject/somepkg/somepkgfile1.go
```

```
package somepkg
type SomeStruct1 struct {...}
type SomeStruct2 struct {...}
func SomeFunc(input SomeStruct1) (output SomeStruct2) {...}
```

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/myproject/mypkg/go.mod
```

```
module gitHub.com/myproject/mypkg
go 1.1.4

require github.com/someproject/somepkg v1.0.0
```

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/someproject/somepkg/somepkgfile1.go
```

```
package somepkg
type SomeStruct1 struct {...}
type SomeStruct2 struct {...}
func SomeFunc() {...}
```

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/someproject/somepkg/go.mod
```

```
module gitHub.com/someproject/somepkg
go 1.1.4

require github.com/someproject/somepkg v1.0.0
```

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/anotherproject/anotherpkpg/somepkgfile1.go
```

```
package main
import (
  "github.com/someproject/somepkg"
  "github.com/myproject/mypkg"
)
func main() {
  // do something with somepkg
  somepkg.SomeFunc()
  s := somepkg.SomeStruct1{...} 
  myData := mypkg.New(s) 
  m := mypkg.MyFunc()
  x := somepkg.SomeStruct1{...}
  y := mypkg.MyFunc(x)
}
```

```
$GOPATH/src/github.com/someproject/somepkg/go.mod
```

```
module gitHub.com/someproject/somepkg
go 1.1.4

require (
  github.com/myproject/mypkg v1.0.0
  github.com/someproject/somepkg v1.0.0
)
```

When I'm building/running anotherpkpg/main.go I keep getting a type mismatch error like:

```
cannot use &s (type *"someproject/somepkg".SomeStruct1) as type *"myproject/mypkg/vendor/github.com/someproject/somepkg".SomeStruct1 in argument to mypkg.New
```

Its not possible at all to be able do this?  I get it that type mismatch can occur if the somepkg are of different version/releases.  But There is no way to reference the vendored somepkg?  I would think it would get even more complex when i

Comment: You cannot use foreign vendored packages, but you should be able to vendor everything in the module you want to use that stuff. You setup seems wired.

Comment: Made a small edit.  But what does "foriegn vendored packages" mean?  That my I can't reference a vendored package's vendor?  I get that.  And I don't have a problem vendoring everything either (like for mypkg and anotherpkg/main).
I suppose its a little complicated when I want don't want a given package to be vendored (assume there are other pkgs in mypkg) and want it to be accessed from GOPATH/GOROOT (like "'somepkg" in this case).

Comment: @Volker, to add a bit more on the "weirdness" the situation is like the somepkg and mypkg are meant to be used independently.  Like a different package/main could just be using mypkg or just sompkg.  They are not meant to be used only with anotherpkg.  So if I were to just use mypkg, I want the mypkg to be using somepkg as its vendor, so that it provides appropriate version control.  Same with somepkg (though it doesn't have any vendor).

Comment: I have no idea what the problem actual is. Best advice probably is: Use Go modules, stick to How to Write Go code and do not vendor.

Comment: @ozn - you can  use `replace` directive to get dependencies for wherever you want: `replace  github.com/someproject/somepkg => ../vendor/...`

Comment: I don't think relative paths are a good idea.  Thats what I keep reading everywhere.  Its just being able to reference it once but will need to vendor it as well.

Answer (score 1):

`vendor` directories work differently in GOPATH mode than in module mode.

Since `github.com/myproject/mypkg/go.mod` exists, you are presumably building `github.com/myproject/mypkg` and its dependencies in module mode. In module mode, only the `vendor` contents for the main module are used, and `vendor` directories for other packages are always ignored, so each package has exactly one location and one definition. (With `-mod=vendor` each package is loaded from your `vendor` directory; with `-mod=readonly` or `-mod=mod` each package is loaded from the module cache.)

Since `github.com/anotherproject/anotherpkg/go.mod` does *not* exist, Go 1.15 and earlier will by default build it in GOPATH mode. In `GOPATH` mode, the `import` statements within each directory refer to the packages in the `vendor` subtrees of all parent directories, and the vendored packages are treated as *distinct packages* even if they share the same import path.

The right long-term fix for your situation is probably to start building `github.com/anotherproject/anotherpkg` in module mode, and to  use a `replace` directive if needed to point it at your working copy of `github.com/myproject/mypkg`.

You can set that up using a sequence of commands like:

```
# Enable module mode for anotherpkg.
cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/anotherproject/anotherpkg
go mod init github.com/anotherproject/anotherpkg

# Use the local copy of github.com/myproject/mypkg instead of the latest GitHub snapshot.
go mod edit -replace github.com/myproject/mypkg=$GOPATH/src/github.com/myproject/mypkg
go get -d github.com/myproject/mypkg

# Resolve any additional missing dependencies to their latest versions.
go mod tidy
```